# Getting errors in && and or operator in bash in if statement

Tags: bash

I'm trying to filter videos based on codec and bitrate.

If codec is xvid or x264 or x265 and bitrate greater than 500 then type = 42
otherwise for xvid and bitrate lower than 500 then type is 2 and x264/x265 and bitrate lower than 500 then type is 54

Is the following way is the right way to go with ?

```
if [ "$PROFILE" == "TV" ]; then
    LEETCAT=TV
    bitrate=$(cat $UP_INFO_FILE | grep "Height"  |  awk -F ':' '{print $2}' | grep -o "[0-9]*" | head -n 1)
    echo "Height: $bitrate"
    if [ "$bitrate" == "" ]; then
        echo Bad bitrate
        continue
    fi
    if [ "$bitrate" -ge "500" ]; then
        LEETTYPE=41
    else
        LEETTYPE=6
    fi

else
    if [ "$PROFILE" == "MOVIE" ]; then
        LEETCAT=Movies
        XviD=$(cat $UP_INFO_FILE | grep "Simple@"  |  awk -F ':' '{print $2}' | grep -o "[0-9]*" | head -n 1)
        X264=$(cat $UP_INFO_FILE | grep "Advanced Video Codec"  |  awk -F ':' '{print $2}' | grep -o "[0-9]*" | head -n 1)
        X264=$(cat $UP_INFO_FILE | grep "High Efficiency Video Codec"  |  awk -F ':' '{print $2}' | grep -o "[0-9]*" | head -n 1)
        bitrate=$(cat $UP_INFO_FILE | grep "Height"  |  awk -F ':' '{print $2}' | grep -o "[0-9]*" | head -n 1)

        echo "Codec: $bitrate"

        if [ "$bitrate" == "" ]; then
            echo Bad bitrate
            continue
        fi

        if [ "$XviD" == "Simple@" ] || [ "$X264" == "Advanced Video Codec" ] || [ "$X265" == "High Efficiency Video Codec" ] && [ "$bitrate" -ge "500" ];
            LEETTYPE=42
        elif [ "$XviD" == "Simple@" ] && [ "$bitrate" -le "499" ]; then
            LEETTYPE=2
        elif [ "$X264" == "Advanced Video Codec" ] || [ "$X265" == "Advanced Video Codec" ] && [ "$bitrate" -le "499" ]; then
            LEETTYPE=54
        fi
        echo $LEETTYPE
    else
        echo Bad profile:$PROFILE
        continue
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Be aware that `&&` and `||` have the *same* precedence in shell; `x || y && z` is equivalent to `(x || y) && z`, not `x || (y && z)`.

Comment: so how do i do it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nesting your `if` statements, use `elif` (else...if...) to test your other scenarios:

```
if [ "$XviD" = "Simple@" ] || [ "$X264" = "Advanced Video Codec" ] || [ "$X265" = "High Efficiency Video Codec" ] && [ "$bitrate" -ge "500" ];
    LEETTYPE=42
elif [ "$XviD" = "Simple@" ] && [ "$bitrate" -le "499" ]; then
    LEETTYPE=2
elif [ "$X264" = "Advanced Video Codec" ] || [ "$X265" = "Advanced Video Codec" ] && [ "$bitrate" -le "499" ]; then
    LEETTYPE=54
fi
```